# Why does Python's rstrip remove more characters than expected?

Tags: python, string, strip

According to the docs the function will strip that sequence of chars from the right side of the string.
The expression `'https://odinultra.ai/api'.rstrip('/api')` should result in the string `'https://odinultra.ai'`.

Instead here is what we get in Python 3:

```
>>> 'https://odinultra.ai/api'.rstrip('/api')
'https://odinultra.'
```

Comment: `rstrip` will remove all combinations of its values.

Comment: what do combination of its values means?

Comment: If you want to remove the suffix use `removesuffix`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip : "The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped" (then they add an example)

Comment: @CorneliuMaftuleac Perhaps `print("piiiiiiieeeee".rstrip("ei"))` would help clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rstrip('/api')` won't remove the suffix `/api`, but a sequence made up of any of the characters `/`, `a`, `p` or `i` from the end of the string. This isn't a bug, but [the documented behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

> The `chars` argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

For your usecase, you should use [`removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) instead:

```py
'https://odinultra.ai/api'.removesuffix('/api')
```

Comment: I see now. Makes sense. The function argument is a bit counterintuitive. Should be a list or a set not a string.